# CKEditor + Rails 4 Installation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ckeditor

Trying to do a nice clean install of CKEditor in a Rails 4 Application

This gem https://github.com/tsechingho/ckeditor-rails

I have a couple problems...

-The first is that I have CKEditor in a form and when I go to that form's page, it only loads a regular text input box.  When I manually reload the same page, CKEditor will load, but only after I reload the page it's on.  It does not show on the first page load.

-Second is that CKEditor is only spitting out raw html.  I'm sure this is just a simple mistake on my part but I havent come across any answers yet.

Here is everything related and per instructions of the gem

**Gemfile**

`gem 'ckeditor_rails'`

**app/assets/javascripts/application.js**

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require ckeditor-jquery
//= require bootstrap
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
$('.ckeditor').ckeditor({
  // optional config
});
```

**app/views/posts/_form.html.erb**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :title %>
    <%= f.text_field :title, class: "form-control" %>
</div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :body %>
    <%= f.text_area :body, class: "ckeditor" %>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.submit class: "btn btn-primary" %>
  </div>
```

This is a full list of console errors/warnings.  All should be from after CKeditor installation.

```
Invalid CSS property name: -webkit-overflow-scrolling style.css:3000
Invalid CSS property value: transform 0.3s ease-out style.css:3997
Invalid CSS property value: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, color-stop(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 0%), color-stop(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0001) 100%)) style.css:4331
Invalid CSS property value: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, color-stop(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0001) 0%), color-stop(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 100%)) style.css:4340
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'appendChild' of undefined ckeditor.js?body=1:74
Uncaught The editor instance "post_body" is already attached to the provided element.
```

Comment: What is your code to attach the images. Mine works except for image upload

Comment: In your application.us file, you include js code, but don't have require self. Also, it's generally advised to separate any code into its own file and include it in the application.is manifest file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future Googlers --

See this [Github Issue](https://github.com/tsechingho/ckeditor-rails/issues/28)

The problem is interference with TurboLinks.  It turns out that the actual page load was not the problem, but rather the link directing to the page with a CKEditor form.  The solution is to disable turbolinks directly from the div containing the link where CKEditor lives.

In my case the solution looked something like this...

_header.html.erb

`<ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right" data-no-turbolink>`